# Notify all clients when specific event happens. Where to subscribe to events?

Tags: c#, wcf

I googled two examples on how I can notify all clients when specific event happens and I'm confused which of them I should use:

Example 1 - http://www.nullskull.com/a/1360/notify-client-applications-using-wcf-callbacks.aspx
Example 2 - http://www.anujvarma.com/wcf-publish-subscribe-a-full-example-the-service-side-part-2-implementation/

In first example event, eventargs etc are placed on client side, in second -  on service side. Where should I place events?

Brief of what I'm trying to achieve: simple card game project that uses local network. I want to notify all clients when one of the clients throws a card (placed it on table and ended his turn) and update they're interfaces, so each client can see thrown card.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use WCF, then you need to implement broadcasting events with a [duplex WCF service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx) (broadcaster service). The first link does mention this.

I think the events you are referring to are the operations that occur on the service and client:

> To create a duplex contract you create a pair of interfaces. The first
>   is the service contract interface that describes the **operations that a
>   client can invoke**. That service contract must specify a callback
>   contract in the ServiceContractAttribute.CallbackContract property.
>   The callback contract is the interface that **defines the operations
>   that the service can call on the client** endpoint.

You may want to also consider using [ASP.NET SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr).

> SignalR allows bi-directional communication between server and client.
>   Servers can now push content to connected clients instantly as it
>   becomes available